# How do you add wcf bindings section to web.config programmatically

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration

When programmatically updating the web.config for a wcf service it's possible to add a behavior by doing...

```
ServiceModelSectionGroup secgroup = (ServiceModelSectionGroup)_webConfig.GetSectionGroup("system.serviceModel");
            ServiceBehaviorElement SerBeh3 = new ServiceBehaviorElement();
            SerBeh3.Name = "AuthenticationSvcWrapBehavior";
            secgroup.Behaviors.ServiceBehaviors.Add(SerBeh3);
```

My question is how you add the binding section?

All I want to do is create a binding with name, Mode and Transport.ClientCredentialType then set the BindingConfiguration to said name for the endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to add the binding section in the config.  Maybe I'm dense but I think the documentation on config changes sucks...

```
//Update Service model   for wcf services         
            ServiceModelSectionGroup secgroup = (ServiceModelSectionGroup)_webConfig.GetSectionGroup("system.serviceModel");

            //Add the binding section with the settings that enable HTTPS communications
            secgroup.Bindings.BasicHttpBinding.Bindings.Add(CreateBasicHttpBinding("SecureWebBinding",
                                                                                   BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport,
                                                                                   HttpClientCredentialType.None));

private BasicHttpBindingElement CreateBasicHttpBinding(string name, BasicHttpSecurityMode mode, HttpClientCredentialType credentialType)
    {
        BasicHttpBindingElement basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBindingElement();
        basicHttpBinding.Name = name;
        basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        return basicHttpBinding;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit it like any other XML file, but I don't think the changes will take effect until you restart the application.

Personally I don't use XML configuration for WCF anymore. The advantages of a pure code solution greatly outweight the drawbacks for me.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback...Curious if you have any examples of how you have done this.  MSDN directly contradicts and says that using code is not a best practice... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731080.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Um.. I should add this as a comment, but apparently my brain just went off the deep end, and I cannot locate the reply link on comments any more :( (Sad brain)
Anyhoo, I was surprised by your assertion that M$ deprecates setting wcf config from code, until I read the link- I would say their intention is that that config files sre prefererrable to code config *which is hard coded* in the code. 
When your binding values come from a dynamic sw config system, code configuration is waaay better thatn file configuration.
heres my code to create a basit http binding, either with or without ssl:

```
    public static BasicHttpBinding GetBinding(string Url, int timeoutSeconds)
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = null;
        UriBuilder urb = new UriBuilder(Url);

        switch (urb.Scheme)
        {
            case "http":
                binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
                break;
            case "https":
                binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("unknown scheme : " + urb.Scheme);
        }
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        if (timeoutSeconds > 0) 
            binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutSeconds);

        return binding;

    }
```

the caller calls

```
   EndpointAddress addr  = new EndpointAddress(url);
   Binding bind =  DataProviderUtilities.GetBinding(_url, timeOutSeconds);
yourserviceClient foo = new yourServiceClient(addr, bind);
```